# *ngFor take two values at once?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm doing an ngFor for print out labels/inputs

```
    <div *ngFor="let point of points" class="form-group row col">
        <label for=... ></label>
        <input ...></input>
    </div>
```

But now I'm realizing that instead of one per row, I want to put two of them on a single row.  Is it possible to do something like that with the ngFor statement?  I know I can add an index to it but I'm still not sure how that would help me as I need to double the internal label/div, and also handle the case where there's not an even number of points, so the last line might just have one pair instead of two.

Comment: Isn't that a styling issue, rather than a structural one? E.g. if you're using flexbox, just let it wrap and make each child 50% the width of the parent. If you really want it to be reflected in the structure, you could iterate over pairs of items.

Comment: It's definitely a styling issue.  But knowing what to google is half the battle :)  I'll go look at flexbox and see if I can figure it out.  Thanks.

Comment: make a jsfiddle or something for us to view what you got so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox approach to achieve 2 column layout of a linear list

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" *ngFor="let point of points" >
    <label for=... ></label>
    <input ...></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  flex: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with Angular, I usually prefer to use `@angular/flex-layout`.
See https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

I've made an example for you declaring a layout row, so that the items are aligned from left to right (I could've used column to stack them from top to bottom) and the wrap attribute says "if there's no more space left, break the line".

Then for every item, I say "take 50% of the whole width" with `fxFlex="50%"`:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
  <app-demo
    *ngFor="let i of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]"
    fxFlex="50%"
    [index]="i"
  ></app-demo>
</div>
```

Here's a Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-xw8ppl